# VBA excel macro to read acess database : How can I get the result of my SQL query(select count(col_name) from table name) in a variable

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub verify_db()

path="c:\temp\temp1.accdb"

  Set cn = CreateObject("Adodb.connection")

  cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & path & ";"

  Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

  rs1.activeconnection = cn

'SQL query to get the count 

strsql = "SELECT count(col_name)  FROM tablename WHERE somecol=some_value"

 rs1.Open strsql

'Result of count which I'm getting through the above SQL query will save in cell 
A1 in sheet named - Sheet1

       Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs1

       count1 = Sheets("input1").Range("A1")

 End sub
```

In the above code I'm getting value for the variable count  indirectly .

How can I get the result directly in the variable count1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
count1 = rs1(0)
```

Where `0` indicates the first column of the results within the recordset.